# Laravel Ajax File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Hello Laravel and Ajax I just started learning. When saving Ajax data, I am saving all data properly. But I'm having trouble uploading pictures. Is there anyone who can help?

//My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request, Blog $blog)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
//            'blog_baslik' => 'required',
//            'blog_icerik' => 'required|string|min:2|max:1750',
////             'blog_resim' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
 
        ]);
 
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
        }
        $blog->storeData($request->all());
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $input['blog_resim'] = time() . '.' . $request->blog_resim. ".jpg";
            $request->blog_resim->move(public_path('image/blog'), $input['image']);
            Blog::create($input);
            return response()->json(['success' => 'done',$input]);
        }
 
    }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// my modal

```
   public function storeData($input)
{
    return static::create($input);
 
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
 
                            var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
                                processing: true,
                                serverSide: true,
                                ajax: "{‌{ route('blog.list') }}",
                                columns: [
                                    {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                                    {data: 'kategori_id', name: 'kategori_id'},
                                    {data: 'blog_baslik', name: 'blog_baslik'},
                                    {data: 'blog_resim', name: 'blog_resim', sortable: false, searchable: false},
                                    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
 
 
                                    {
                                        data: 'action',
                                        name: 'action',
                                        orderable: true,
                                        searchable: true
                                    },
                                ]
                            });
                        });
///ekleme işlemi
                        // Create article Ajax request.
                        $('#SubmitCreateArticleForm').click(function(e) {
                            CKEDITOR.instances['blog_icerik'].updateElement();
 
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                }
                            });
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "{‌{ route('blog.store') }}",
                                method: 'post',
                                data: {
                                    kategori_id: $('#kategori_id').val(),
                                    blog_baslik: $('#blog_baslik').val(),
                                    blog_icerik: $('#blog_icerik').val(),
                                    blog_resim: $('#blog_resim').val(),
                                    blog_meta_title: $('#blog_meta_title').val(),
                                    blog_meta_desc: $('#blog_meta_desc').val(),
 
                                },
 
                                success: function(result) {
                                    if(result.errors) {
                                        $('.alert-danger').html('');
                                        $.each(result.errors, function(key, value) {
                                            $('.alert-danger').show();
                                            $('.alert-danger').append('<strong><li>'+value+'</li></strong>');
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        $('.alert-danger').hide();
                                        $('.alert-success').show();
                                        $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                                        setInterval(function() {
                                            $('.alert-success').hide();
                                            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                                            $('#CreateArticleModal').modal('hide');
 
                                        }, 2000);
                                    }
                                }
                                    });
                        });
 
                        // Silme İşlemleri
                        var deleteID;
                        $('body').on('click', '#getDeleteId', function () {
                            deleteID = $(this).data('id');
                        })
                        $('#SubmitDeleteArticleForm').click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var id = deleteID;
                            $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                }
                            });
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "blog/" + id,
                                method: 'DELETE',
                                success: function (result) {
                                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                                    $('#DeleteArticleModal').hide();
                                    $('.alert-success').show();
                                    $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
 
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the troubles you are having?

Comment: https://ibb.co/RPPv7ym                                                                   I cannot upload a picture.appears as fakepath and does not load the picture. I want upload ajax image

Comment: You can't upload pictures from your local hard drive. You have to upload them to your server and use the server directory. `localhost/C:\ ` is an illegal URL

Comment: I can not upload. When Ajax sends a request, it creates its own fakepath. I just want to learn how to fix this.

Comment: How are you uploading the file?

Comment: you can see my code

Comment: I can't really understand what all of your code is doing. Learn [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)